# Projections on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $A\subset\Omega$ be a non-empty connected open set.
Assume that there exists a constant $R>0$ such that
$$
(1) \qquad \text{dist}(x, \partial A) = \text{dist}(x, \partial \Omega) - R,
\qquad \forall x\in A,
$$
where $\text{dist}(x, K) := \min_{y\in K} |x-y|$ for every closed set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to prove (or disprove...) that $A$ is a connected component of the set $\Omega_R := \{x\in\Omega:\ \text{dist}(x, \partial\Omega) > R\}$.

It is not difficult to show that $A\subseteq\Omega_R$.

In particular, if $B$ is a connected component of $\Omega_R$ such that
$A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, then $A\subset B$, and we have to prove that $A=B$.

Since now, I have proved the following property that seems to be useful:
$$
(2)\qquad x\in A,\
y\in \Pi_{\partial A}(x)
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
z := y + R\, \frac{y-x}{|y-x|}\in\Pi_{\partial\Omega}(x),
$$ 
where $\Pi_K(x)$ is the set of projections of $x$ on $K$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try following:
for every boundary point $y \in \partial A$ take a look at a point $x\in A$ which is really close to it, say $\text{dist}(x,y) = \varepsilon$. You will get that distance from $x$ to $\partial \Omega$ is not more than $R+\varepsilon$ and hence the distance from $y$ to $\partial \Omega$ in not more than $R + 2\varepsilon$.

Now consider $\varepsilon \to 0$, you will get that $\partial A \subset \{x\in \Omega \mid \text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)\le R\}$. Therefore  $\partial A \cap \{x\in \Omega \mid \text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)> R\} = \partial A \cap \Omega_R = \emptyset$.

From here you can probably prove what you need.

Comment: From (2) I already know that $\partial A \subset \partial\Omega_R$, but it's not clear to me how to prove that $A=B$.

Comment: @Rigel Well try proving that if $A \neq B$ then $\partial A$ has points in $B$?

Comment: @Rigel like that for example: say $\partial A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $B = A \cup (B \setminus A\setminus \partial A)$ and hence $B$ is not connected.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.